# Why such a long delay on the delivery of my hats?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, hats

After surfing/voting/closing on Programmers this morning, I realized that I had earned a few hats! When I went to check where they were at so that I could show them off, I found that some of the hats that I met the criteria for still aren't there after >20 minutes!

I'm guessing hats are going to take longer than badges to get and be seen, but why such a long wait? When will I get my precious hats?

Comment: explained at MSO: [Winter Bash hats delay](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159136/165773). Actually all the questions about hats I had so far (about handful I think) turned out to be already asked and answered in **[MSO tag: winterbash](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winterbash)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a small delay (anywhere from 30m to 2h) for hats, similar to how badges sometimes take a while to appear, the server side scripts that award them run periodically.

Patience young grasshopper!